# Android clear Activity back stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, back

I have some activities, by example A, B, C, D
How can I finish Activity D, clear back stack, to avoid returning on Activity C, and return to Activity B.
Please, not purpose start D from C for result and in onActivityResult in C, invoke finish again=) 'cause finish() is already used))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

See the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) here. It actually uses the exact example you gave:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if that behavior needs on permanent bases or it's conditional. In first case you can add in your `D` manifest activity declaration following line:

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.B"
```

In second case you can override in activity `D` - `onBackPressed()` method and start `Activity B` from here depends on current situation.